# Is Database should be distributed when I use it as a persistence storage for Storm in Distributed Mode

Tags: mysql, streaming, real-time, apache-storm, real-time-updates

I have a Storm cluster which consists of Nimbus and 4 Supervisors, and I have MySQL installed on the same node as Nimbus:
Cluster information

1. **Nimbus** - 192.168.0.1
2. **Supervisors** - 192.168.0.2 ~ 5
3. **MySQL** - same as the Nimbus, bind to 0.0.0.0 (so that I can connect remotely)

I am trying to update MySQL table in realtime, so if my bolt is running, say, on ...4 node, how does this node(bolt) sends data (update) to the MySQL server which is running on another node. In Hadoop, we have HDFS which is available on all nodes of a cluster, my question is Do I need some Distributed Storage for store tuples or I should make some configuration changes to my MySQL or Storm topology

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to open a database connection from each node to your MySQL installation. The connection will go over the network, thus, you can update your DB remotely.